# Payment in Lyft API

Tags: postman, lyft-api

Once dropped off how do i make payment to lyft.

I am using stripe as payment mechanism but cannot find any endpoint wherein i can pass the charge to actually make payment to lyft.

I do see that i can make a tip through this endpoint 
https://developer.lyft.com/reference#ride-request-rating-and-tipping

and also ride receipt is generated after payment
[Ride receipt](https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides/ride_id/receipt) but what i cannot figure out is where exactly the payment is made

Answer (score 0):

Lyft automatically charged the user's default personal payment.  At this time, they don't allow you to select different payment methods.  You must call the PUT /rides/:id endpoint with the rating and tip amount to close out the ride and grab the ride receipt via the webhook.

Online reference:
https://developer.lyft.com/v1/reference

[image]